# Azure anomaly detector parameters

Tags: azure-anomaly-detection

I'm trialing the azure anomaly detector API (with C#) for alert conditions in my organisation.  Data is formatted and ordered correctly, and the API returns a result as expected, using the last data point technique.  What I'm struggling to understand is how the following parameters interact with each other:

- Sensitivity
- MaxAnomalyRatio
- Period

Documentation [here](https://westus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/AnomalyDetector/operations/post-timeseries-entire-detect) only really lists types and vague ranges.  Are there any specific, detailed examples showing what these parameters are and how they interact?

Comment: Partial Answer:  Period has been explained here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/anomaly-detector/concepts/anomaly-detection-best-practices

Answer (score 1):

This blog article has details on the max anomaly ratio I found very helpful: https://www.smartercode.io/how-azure-anomaly-detection-api-allows-you-to-find-weirdness-inside-crowd-part-2/

> [Optional] Maximum Anomaly Ratio: Advanced model parameter; Between 0 and less than 0.5, it tells the maximum percentage of points that can be determined as anomalies. You can think of it as a mechanism to limit the top anomaly candidates.